# Query YouTube API (v2 vs v3) for Titles

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

What's the best way to query the YouTube API for Titles?

**API V2**

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/DAb-ru6rjXs?v=2
```

**API V3**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=DAb-ru6rjXs&key=MYKEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
```

I have a large list of video ID's, that need to query the API via Ruby and output to csv.

Comment: As you have indicated you are using Ruby, could you add which gem you are using, and any code you have so far that explains what you need (even a couple of variables that indicate your starting data structure would help).

Comment: Do you want to get title for each video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use Data API v3 videos->list call. You can join all video id's with a comma for batching. I used three video ids below as an example

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=iXOUIsu-E0Q%2C+LWoBXHDeJSY%2C+Xz5z1hBxejg&fields=items%2Fsnippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the existence of batching calls in v3 -- really important when needing to get lots of titles for lots of vids.

Answer (score 2):

You can check https://github.com/jamesshipton/simple_youtube.

Pretty simple

```
:get top 5 'ruby on rails' videos

gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=ruby+on+rails&max-results=5&v=2

video_search = Youtube::Video.find(:params => {:q => 'ruby on rails', :"max-results" => '5', :v => '2'})
video_search.entry.size             # => 5
video_search.title                  # => "YouTube Videos matching query: ruby on rails"
video_search.entry[3].link[1].href  # => gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/UCB57Npj9U0/responses?v=2
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the title, you have to specify it in the field parameter.

```
fields=items(snippet(title))
```

Add your developer key at the end of this URL and give it a try

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=iXOUIsu-E0Q%2C+LWoBXHDeJSY%2C+Xz5z1hBxejg&fields=items(snippet(title))&key=YourDeveloperKey
```

Maybe also this gem can be helpful https://github.com/edap/yourub